# Public Global Variable or get() and set() methods?

Tags: c++

What is better way to access and modify variables of a particular class in other class? Using public global variable or using get() and set()?

Comment: Don't have public data members. Anything public is forever part of the API that you need to support until your dying day.

Comment: ...or if only used in own projects: you need a) a very  good refactoring tool or b) regex search and replace skills if every changing the data members. ;)

Comment: Beware of [quasi classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Comment: third alternative: declare the other class as `friend`

Comment: So get() and set() methods should be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of public members or dedicated setter and getter methods, try to provide any logic linked to your class with your interface.

I.e. the length of a vector is logically linked to the vector itself so you would not want to provide any facility for the rest of your program to access your data directly or indirect but provide the length as part of your interface.

#### Example getter:

```
class v2d
{
  double mx, my;
public:
  double get_x() const { return mx; }
  double get_y() const { return my; }
};

bool foo (v2d const &v)
{
  using std::sqrt;
  return sqrt(v.get_x()*v.get_x() + v.get_y()*v.get_y()) > 1.0;
}
```

#### Example length interface:

```
class v2d
{
  double mx, my;
public:
  double len () const
  {
    using std::sqrt;
    return sqrt(mx*mx + my*my);
  }
};

void foo (v2d const &v)
{
  return v.len() > 1.0;
}
```

Using the second you're free to change the data members (i.e. replace both by one `double m[2];` ...).

The same goes for setters as well: Provide class alteration logic as part of a meaningful interface.

#### Example getter and setter:

```
class v2d
{
  double mx, my;
public:
  void set_x(double new_x) { mx = new_x; }
  void set_y(double new_y) { my = new_y; }
  double get_x() const { return mx; }
  double get_y() const { return my; }
};

void normalize (v2d &v)
{
  using std::sqrt;
  double const len = sqrt(v.get_x()*v.get_x() + v.get_y()*v.get_y());
  v.set_x(v.get_x()/len);
  v.set_y(v.get_y()/len);
}
```

#### Example meaningful interface:

```
class v2d
{
  double mx, my;
public:
  double len () const
  {
    using std::sqrt;
    return sqrt(mx*mx + my*my);
  }
  v2d& operator/= (double const factor)
  {
    mx /= factor;
    my /= factor;
    return *this;
  }
};

void normalize (v2d &v)
{
  v /= v.len();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really so lazy, just use public.

If you want your code maintainable, use *get* and *set*.

Comment: there is no other benefit of using get and set?

Comment: add safety check in setter? there're a lot of benefit to use get/set. Try Google.

Answer (score 0):

Public data members aren't uder your controll. You or user of your code can access them from anywhere so you cannot change them.

Simply example - if you want to change datatype of global variable, you have to change code everywhere you acces it. If you have setter and getter you simply add conversion to them.

With setters and getters you can add checking if input or output is valid and safe.